# Discounted Cumulative Gain dcg_score sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.metrics import ndcg_score, dcg_score
import numpy as np
  
actual= [3,2,0,0,1]
ideal= sorted(actual, reverse=True)

#list to np asarray
actualarr=np.asarray([actual])
idealarr= np.asarray([ideal])
print ("actual score as array", actualarr)
print("ideal score as array", idealarr)

#Discounted Cumulative Gain
dcg= dcg_score(idealarr, actualarr)
print("DCG: ", dcg)
```

I don't understand why `dcg_score` takes y_score as a parameter. When I work out DCG longhand (sum relevance/log2(i+1)) I can get the same answer ~4.6, but i can achieve this just with the true scores `[3,2,0,0,1]`, so why does it also require the ideal score `[3,2,1,0,0]` in the function?

Answer (score 0):

I understood that `sklearn.metrics.ndcg` computes its sum by taking values from `y_true` as if it was reordered according to `y_score`.

As explained inside the [code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/36958fb240fbe435673a9e3c52e769f01f36bec0/sklearn/metrics/_ranking.py#L1261): "Sum the true scores ranked in the order induced by the predicted scores"

This means the metric is computed on the induced ranking, using true relevance values.

A small example:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import dcg_score

def naive_dcg(y_score):
    score = 0
    for i,n in enumerate(y_score[0]):
        num = 2**n -1
        den = np.log2(i+1+1)
        score += num/den
    return score

y_true = [[1,0]]
y_score = [[0,1]]

print(f'sklearn: {dcg_score(y_true,y_score):.2}, naive: {naive_dcg(y_score):.2}')

y_score = [[0.1,0.2]]

print(f'sklearn: {dcg_score(y_true,y_score):.2}, naive: {naive_dcg(y_score):.2}')
```

outputs:

```
sklearn: 0.63, naive: 0.63
sklearn: 0.63, naive: 0.17
```

which shows naive produces a different metric for the same ranking order.